# node.js : async.each gets too slow with large number of elements to process asynchronously

Tags: node.js, memory-management, gridfs

I have a system with 4GB of RAM. I need to process a set of 200 files (average file size = 20MB) in the following manner:

- read each file from gridfs
- extract some information from the file
- store the info to some collection in mongoDB

Now the code, for doing the same is:

```
async.each(files, function (file, callback){

    console.log("reading file", file._id);

    readstream[file._id] = db.gfs().createReadStream({
        _id: file._id
    });

    readstream[file._id].on('data', function (chunk) {
        part[file._id] = part[file._id] && (part[file._id] + chunk.toString()) || chunk.toString();
    });

    readstream[file._id].on('end', function(){

        //  do something here 

    });

}, function (err){
    if(err){
        console.error("error ", err);
        res.json(err);
    }               
    else{
        console.log("saved all files ############ YIPPIEEEEEEEEEEEEE ###################");
        res.json({"status": 1});
    }
});
```

It works like charm for 10 files. When the number of files is large (200 in my case), it gets really slow, possibly due to memory limits.

For now, I can process the files 10 at a time and live with it since its a one time activity. But I wanted to know what is the standard practice for tackling such situations in production ?

Comment: How big are these files? If it's a memory problem then ultimately you need to look at the hardware, scaling out rather than up would be the correct approach here.

Comment: `async.each` takes all tasks and execute them in parallel, try to use `async.eachSeries` instead where the execution is taking place for the tasks one by one, if you still need to do a parallel execution you may want to take a look at `async.cargo` which is basically a combination of both "each, and eachSeries".

Comment: Perhaps you could refactor to use the async function eachLimit [link](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) or parallelLimit?  [link](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback).  This executes tasks in parallel up to a specified number.  i.e. you could limit it to 10 and it would run the first 10, then as each of the 10 finishes, it would start another, until all were done.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash : async.eachSeries did the trick. Thanks!!! :-)
You may post it as an answer so that I can close this question

Comment: I am going to post this as an answer so that it will be useful to others, please accept it to indicate that this helped solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lays down to parallel execution as `async.each` executes all the tasks in parallel, as a workaround, you may use [async.eachSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) to execute the tasks one by one, you may also consider using [async.cargo](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#cargo) to combine the execution of multiple tasks in shots.

Comment: just for the record, although it worked way better than async.each but when the number of files and size of each file was large (around 100 files 30 MB each), even this did not help.

Comment: Give `async.cargo` a try and share your experience

Comment: my bad. its working perfectly fine. There was a nested async.each as well which was causing problem. Now changed that to async.easchSeries as well. Running fine so far since 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [async.eachLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit).
`limit` here is the maximum number of async operations at a time. this will restrain async
to run N amount of tasks in parallel.

Async docs:

> The same as each but runs a maximum of limit async operations at a
> time.

Example (not tested but that is the idea of processing 10 files at a time):

```
filesContent = []
async.eachLimit(fileNamesArray, 10, function(fileName, callback) {
    // Process a file
    processFile(fileName, (err, content) => {
        filesContent.push(content);
        callback(err);
    });
}, function(err) {
    // if any of tasks produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```